# JavaFX, extracting all children that are buttons from root.getChildren()

Tags: java, javafx

I just start my journey with JavaFX and I'll try to make a simple calc.

I have that code to make all my buttons:

```
Button one = new Button("1");
Button two = new Button("2");
Button three = new Button("3");
Button four = new Button("4");
Button five = new Button("5");
Button six = new Button("6");
Button seven = new Button("7");
Button eight = new Button("8");
Button nine = new Button("9");
Button zero = new Button("0");
Button dot = new Button(".");
Button pow = new Button("^2");
TextField equation = new TextField();
Button equal = new Button("=");
Button multiple = new Button("*");
Button divide = new Button("/");
Button takefrom = new Button("-");
Button add = new Button("+");
```

In the start method ill add them all to the boxes and then to the root. My main class implements EvendHandler. Now i want apply .onAction(this), to each button.

**There is a way to extract only buttons from root node?**
I tried getChildren() and then for each but I can't get it to work.

**Is there a good habit to make a arraylist for my buttons only and then make a loop that can do it?**

**Or there is another way?**

All code can be found at: 
http://pastebin.com/RBzbn8bT

Comment: Do you want to apply all your buttons to do the same thing when you press them? Probably not.

Comment: put the relevant code in the question instead of linking a repo

Comment: I want to add the same event handler to all my buttons, check the source, and than make something

Comment: Why? It is much better practice to use a different handler for each button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* use an `instanceof` test for this, or (with a bit of trickery) do a [`lookup`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookupAll-java.lang.String-). But neither of these are particularly nice solutions: a more elegant solution is just to define one or more methods for creating the buttons, and put all the code you need for each button there. That way you can easily define a different handler for each button.

This basic idea is something like:

```
public class Calculator extends Application {

    private GridPane root ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        root = new GridPane()

        // zero button:
        root.add(1, 4, createNumericalButton(0));

        // buttons for 1-9:
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 9 ; i++) {
            Button button = createNumericalButton(i);
            int row = 2 - (i-1)/3 ; // {7,8,9} -> 0; {4,5,6} -> 1; {1,2,3}->2
            int col = (i-1) % 3 ;
            root.add(col, row, button);
        }

        // other layout...

    }

    private Button createNumericalButton(final int n) {
        Button button = new Button(Integer.toString(n));
        button.setMinSize(32, 32);
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            // replace with real handler...
            System.out.println("Pressed "+n);
        }
        return button ;
    }
}
```

You can similarly define a `createOperationButton(...)` method for creating the buttons for `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/` etc. If you want to get a bit more sophisticated, that method could take a [`DoubleBinaryOperator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/DoubleBinaryOperator.html) as a parameter, for specifying the behavior of each button. So you'd end up doing something like:

```
root.add(4, 3, createOperationButton("+", (x, y) -> x + y));
root.add(4, 2, createOperationButton("-", (x, y) -> x - y));
root.add(4, 1, createOperationButton("*", (x, y) -> x * y));
root.add(4, 0, createOperationButton("/", (x, y) -> x / y));
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to extract only buttons, you can use the instanceof keyword.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

In your case, you could iterate through all the children of your root and check if they belong to the Button class.

For example:

```
for(int i=0; i<root.getChildren().size(); i++)
    if(root.getChildren().get(i) instanceof Button) {
        your code here
    }
```